# Nuxt.js, автозаполнение headers в axios глобально

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt.config, хочу заполнить хедеры на axios с использованием токена, который храниться в localStorage. Вот как я это реализовывал

```
 axios: {
    withCredentials: false,
    common: {
      'CRM-Auth-Token': this.localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
  },
```

Но при пересборке - Nuxt ругаеться на getItem - и говорит что такого свойства нету - undefined, подскажите что не так делаю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо создать конфигурационный файл и подключить его в `plugins`.

**nuxt.config:**

```
plugins: ['@/plugins/axios'],  
modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios']
```

**axios.js:**

```
export default function ({ $axios, store }) {
  $axios.onRequest((config) => { 
    config.headers.common['CRM-Auth-Token'] = store.state.token
  }) 
}
```

**store.js:**

```
...
state: { 
  token: 'тут должен быть ваш токен'
}
...
```

Токен соответственно вы можете записать откуда угодно в store.

Если будут вопросы - оставляйте комментарий :)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Очень сильно помогло! И Сэкономило пару десятков строк)